# Python numpy: Convert string in to numpy array

Tags: python, vector, numpy, trigonometry

I have following String that I have put together:

```
v1fColor = '2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3'
```

I am treating it as a vector: Long story short its a forecolor of an image histogram:

I have the following lambda function to calculate cosine similarity of two images, So I tried to convert this is to numpy.array but I failed:

Here is my lambda function

```
import numpy as NP
import numpy.linalg as LA
cx = lambda a, b : round(NP.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 3)
```

So I tried the following to convert this string as a numpy array:

```
v1fColor = NP.array([float(v1fColor)], dtype=NP.uint8)
```

But I ended up getting following error:

```
    v1fColor = NP.array([float(v1fColor)], dtype=NP.uint8)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this answer so if for any future references: I am not sure what is the correct solution in this case but I think What @David Robinson initially publish was the correct answer due to one reason: Cosine Similarity values can not be greater than one and when I use `NP.array(v1fColor.split(","), dtype=NP.uint8)` option I get strage values which are above 1.0 for cosine similarity between two vectors.

So I wrote a simple sample code to try out:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA

def testFunction():
    value1 = '2,3,0,80,125,15,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
    value2 = '2,137,0,4,96,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
    cx = lambda a, b : round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 3)
    #v1fColor = np.array(map(int,value1.split(',')))
    #v2fColor =  np.array(map(int,value2.split(',')))
    v1fColor = np.array( value1.split(','), dtype=np.uint8 )
    v2fColor = np.array( value2.split(','), dtype=np.uint8 )
    print v1fColor
    print v2fColor
    cosineValue = cx(v1fColor, v2fColor)
    print cosineValue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testFunction()
```

if you run this code you should get the following output:
[image]

Not lets un commented two lines that and run the code with the David's Initial Solution:

```
v1fColor = np.array(map(int,value1.split(',')))
v2fColor =  np.array(map(int,value2.split(',')))
```

Keep in mind as you see above Cosine Similarity Value came up above 1.0 but when we use the map function and use do the int casting we get the following value which is the correct value:

[image]

Luckily I was plotting the values that I was initially getting and some of the cosine values came above 1.0 and I took the outputs of these vectors and manually typed it in python console, and send it via my lambda function and got the correct answer so I was very confuse. Then I wrote the test script to see whats going on and glad I caught this issue. I am not a python expert to exactly tell what is going on in two methods to give two different answers. But I leave that to either @David Robinson or @mgilson.

Comment: quick comment.  In the "david" form of solution, do something like `np.array(map(int,v1fColor.split(',')),dtype=np.uint8))` and I'm guessing you'll get the same thing you got in my solution.  I'm guessing the problem is the data-type (which we were just preserving from your original question).  What's probably happening is when you take the inner product of the two arrays, you're getting numbers greater than 255 -- e.g. (2*128) will probably result in 0

Answer (score 11):

You have to split the string by its commas first:

```
NP.array(v1fColor.split(","), dtype=NP.uint8)
```

Comment: I just learned that numpy will do the string conversions implicitly a few weeks ago.  I think that's the coolest thing ever.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without using python string methods -- try [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
>>> numpy.fromstring(v1fColor, dtype='uint8', sep=',')
array([ 2,  4, 14,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12,  4,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15,  6,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20,  9,  0,  0,  0,
        2,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13,  6,  0,  0,  0,  1,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10,  8,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 17, 17,  0,  0,  0,  3,  6,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  5,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  3,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  6,  0,  0,  0,  2,  3], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: (+1) I think this is the way to go here.  (I actually just learned about `fromstring` today through a different question)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
lst = v1fColor.split(',')  #create a list of strings, splitting on the commas.
v1fColor = NP.array( lst, dtype=NP.uint8 ) #numpy converts the strings.  Nifty!
```

or more concisely:

```
v1fColor = NP.array( v1fColor.split(','), dtype=NP.uint8 )
```

Note that it is a little more customary to do:

```
import numpy as np
```

compared to `import numpy as NP`

**EDIT**

Just today I learned about the function `numpy.fromstring` which could also be used to solve this problem:

```
NP.fromstring( "1,2,3" , sep="," , dtype=NP.uint8 )
```

Comment: Sure thanks, I will add that change too.. by the way really tough case, because both answers are great and I am not sure which one to pick... :)

Comment: Neither of us would take it personally :)

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis -- they're pretty much the same answer.  Just pick David Robinsons'.  He's got a cooler name than me anyway -- Also, I already got my 200 rep for today ...

Comment: I get that a lot. Pick @mgilson, he knew about the implicit conversion to a float.

Comment: @mgilson knows full well that accepted answers aren't counted towards the 200 rep limit. He's trying to trick you.

Comment: you are right @mgilson David Robinson do have a cooler name sorry stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do two mentions :(... LOL

Comment: @DavidRobinson *sigh* you were supposed to just go with it ... Thanks though.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis -- just today I learned of a new function in numpy which would also solve this problem (see my edit)

Comment: @mgilson I am actually am getting strage values could please update the version you had with float or long in it I think that was your original asnwer before David pointed out this version. Thanks.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis -- what's wrong?  looking at the edit history, I haven't really changed anything as far as content is concerned.  The version that DavidRobinson posted was something like `np.array(map(int,v1fColor.split(',')))`, but that should be equivalent to what I posted.  You can always change the dtype from `np.uint8` to `int`, or `np.int32` ... (`np.uint8` should be limited to the range 0-255).

Comment: @mgilson Thanks I will be posting a question because I went over and over to figure whats going on in these values hope you will get a chance to take a look at it.. Look for title like Python: Cosine Similarity using Numpy etc.

Comment: @mgilson wow that was the issue so let me send you two vectors and i just tried out both the functions and Davids solution work because cosine values cannot be greater than 1

Comment: @mgilson I just posted as an answer to this question hope that is ok. I put details to best of my knowledge please feel free to do any edits. I am not sure if i am suppose to answer my own question but I thought we are going through go answer discussion so I didn't want to start a new thread.