# Find the lengths of list within numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `arr` which is shaped `(100,)`

```
  arr.shape()  #(100,)
```

here are 100 lists within this array. The lists are strings of characters with no spaces, around length 30

```
'TBTBBBBBBBBBEBEBEBEBDLKDJFDFIKKKKK'
```

This array has a "matrix-esque" shape. How can I either (a) tell the lengths of each of the lists in this array or (b) reformat this array so that `arr.shape()` gives me two dimensions, i.e. `arr.shape()` gives (100,30)?

Also, it may not be that every list is of the same length (some may be 28, not 30):

How can I check for this behavior? What will `numpy.shape()` output in such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to determine the length of each string in the array:

```
arr = np.array(['aasdfads', 'asfdads', 'fdfsdfaf'])
>>> [len(i) for i in arr]
[8, 7, 8]
```

Or take the max:

```
>>> max([len(i) for i in arr])
8
```

Comment: Could I somehow splice the string to input each element into a numpy array using numpy.asarray()? What would the different shapes result in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747125/python-numpy-convert-string-in-to-numpy-array\