# More elegant method to take user-input vector as a float64?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm reprogramming an orbital analysis program that I wrote in MATlab in Python 3.7. The initial inputs of velocity and position are queried user inputs. The method I'm using currently is clunky feeling (I am a python beginner) and I'm wondering if someone can suggest a more elegant method to take this input vector as a numpy float64? I suspect this problem is trivial but I haven't found a clear answer yet...

The current input is a vector with the syntax: "i,k,j". no spaces, comma delimited. Each component is converted to a float64 in a list via list(map(float, input)), I then have to convert it back to numpy float64 in order to use r as a vector later on.

```py
v = np.float64(list(map(np.float64,input('Query Text').split(','))))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python numpy: Convert string in to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747125/python-numpy-convert-string-in-to-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that's pretty elegant already. I'd do it like this if you like it better:

```py
np.float64(
    [np.float64(i) for i in input("Query text").split(",")]
)
```

but i wouldn't say this is much more elegant, but at least it does the same thing.